# Location counter not changing

Tags: linker, embedded-linux, linker-scripts

I have a linker script like the one below :

....

```
.MemSection :
{
    _MEM_SEC_BEGIN = . ;

    *(.bss .vbss.* .section.*)

    *(.common)

    _MEM_SEC_END = . ;

} > RAM

_MEM_SEC_END_OUTSIDE = . ;

ASSERT( (_MEM_SEC_END_OUTSIDE == _MEM_SEC_END) , "Warning message" )

ASSERT( (_MEM_SEC_END_OUTSIDE != _MEM_SEC_BEGIN) , "Warning message" )
```

....

All the names are fictive , but the structure is the same. 
The problem is that asserts are failing , I don't know why my location counter is not changing . Please keep in mind that my .MemSection is not empty . 
In which situation the location counter could remain the same after an output section definition ?

Thank you !

Comment: Are you sure that `.bss` , `.vbss`, `.section` and `.common` are not empty? Could you add the map file?

Comment: The problem was that .MemSection is .tbss , and for this memory section the location counter is not change automatically .